# React Native FlatList component is not rendering my array

Tags: javascript, react-native

So, I am trying to make an app using react-native and i need a list, i am using FlatList. **It seems like the problem is in the saving when i use console.log()** (I save and retrieve in different files(screens), could that be the problem?).I am getting my array from async storage:

```
try {
  if ((await AsyncStorage.getItem("DA")) !== null) {
    DUES = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("DA"));
    Works = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("WA"));
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("DA");
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("WA");
  }
  if ((await AsyncStorage.getItem("DUES")) !== null) {
    DUES.push(await AsyncStorage.getItem("DUES"));
    Works.push(await AsyncStorage.getItem("Info"));
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("DUES");
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("Info");
  }
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("DA", JSON.stringify(DUES));
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("WA", JSON.stringify(Works));
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

And i need to display that on the list, but nothing renders.
List code:

```
<FlatList>
      data={Works}
      renderItem=
      {() => {
        <Card>
          <Text>{Works[i]}</Text>
          <Text>Due: {DUES[i]}</Text>
        </Card>;
        i++;
      }}
</FlatList>
```

Save script:

```
      onPress={async () => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.multiSet([
            ["DUES", D],
            ["Info", Title],
          ]);
          console.log("DONE2");
          Alert.alert("Saved!");
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }}
```

It might be because i am missing the "key", but idk. How should i fix this?, and make it render the list. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're supposed to use `renderItem={({ item, index } => <Card>...</Card>}` (`item` is `Works[i]` already, and there's no need to manually increment `i`); this basically works like when you use `Array.map` to render a list in React), see the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem

Comment: Are you properly using `setState` after reading `Works`? Because that's how React works: the app re-renders after a state change. If `Works` starts out as empty array, the list will never appear unless you call `this.setState({ Works: ... });` If you haven't used React before, I'd recommend learning React first before jumping into React native.

Comment: Oh, I dont. How should i do that?

Comment: Using state is a fundamental technique of React. I suggest starting here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not returning the elements that you need to print out in your renderItem method of FlatList component.
Instead try this:

```
<FlatList>
      data={Works}
      renderItem=
      {({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          <Card>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <Text>Due: {DUES[index]}</Text>
          </Card>
        );
      }}
</FlatList>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check if it works now.

Comment: It's `({ item, index })`

Comment: Hmm, ill test that.

Comment: Hmm, Nope, did not work, it seems like there is something wrong with the saving, seems the arrays exist (logging).

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

```js
try {
  const [da, work] = await Promise.all([
    AsyncStorage.getItem("DA"),
    AsyncStorage.getItem("WA")
  ]);

  if (da !== null) {
    DUES = JSON.parse(da);
    Works = JSON.parse(work);
  }

  const [dues, info] = await Promise.all([
    AsyncStorage.getItem("DUES"),
    AsyncStorage.getItem("Info")
  ]);

  if (dues !== null) {
    DUES.push(dues);
    Works.push(info);

    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("DUES");
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("Info");
  }

  await Promise.all([
    AsyncStorage.setItem("DA", JSON.stringify(DUES)),
    AsyncStorage.setItem("WA", JSON.stringify(Works))
  ]);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Then your list:

```js
<FlatList>
      data={Works}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return <Card>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
          <Text>Due: {DUES[index]}</Text>
        </Card>;
      }}
</FlatList>
```

You could also combine dues and work into a single array of object kind of thing, I guess.

Comment: Ill try that, Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but answering this is pointless since OP isn't using `state`.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just informing you of the recent development that renders this question moot; for all we know, the code that OP shows might work perfectly fine in theory.